# symlink's Last access time does not updates in windows 7

Tags: symbolic-link

I am stuck around with a problem which is something as follows:

i have a symlink at my desktop and the original file is in my local partition (Say D: drive)

whenever i update the original file, contents of the file reflects in the soft link.However,

the Last Accessed Time remains same.

Is there any option to sync the last Access time of the soft link with the Last Accessed time of the original file??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the filetimes displayed are only updated as-needed.  So you would need to access the file through the not yet updated link to get the updated filetime.